# What is the best way to send big arrays with AllJoyn

Tags: arrays, chunks, alljoyn

According to specification, AllJoyn limits the array size to ALLJOYN_MAX_ARRAY_LEN = 2^17 bytes when DBus has a greater limit of 2^26.

I have a case where I need to send images as array of bytes ('ay' signature) that, even compressed, can be bigger than 2^17 bytes.

There are different ways to achieve this, for example splitting the array and adding an array ID and number of chunk, rebuilding the correct array on the other side.

I was wondering if anyone came into a similar problem and what approach would work best.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a Bulk Data Transfer interface has been specified and is being reviewed by the AllSeen Alliance interface review board.  It does not look like it has been approved yet.  Also it does not look like anyone has created an implementation of the interface at this time.

https://git.allseenalliance.org/gerrit/#/c/5977